# Define function to select columns by name, Dataframe Python

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I do have a dataframe with 1000 Simulations and I would like to define a function which allows me to select one columns by their names

The dataframe Looks as follows:

```
SIMULATION     Sim_1     Sim_2     Sim_3     Sim_4     Sim_5     Sim_6     
2016        0.013765  0.012882  0.006664  0.019607  0.010095  0.020073   
2017        0.016176  0.014744  0.009644  0.022152  0.013778  0.018454   
2018        0.018562  0.016773  0.014824  0.020529  0.018414  0.012878   
2019        0.027624  0.009368  0.016195  0.022941  0.025510  0.002396   
2020        0.037297 -0.000171  0.019798  0.021232  0.028369  0.001007   
2021        0.040634 -0.002396  0.024508  0.018794  0.027421  0.007584
```

To select one columns one could type

```
df.Sim_1
```

This would give me the first column

Is there a possibilty to define a function? I have tried

```
def select(data, sim_nr):
    sim = data.sim_nr()
    return(sim)
```

But applying this function to a dataset gives me an error

```
select(f("I:/tools/python/ESG/yield_RN_FY15_mitVA_BC.FAC",20), "Sim_1")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `[]` for selecting column:

```
def select(data, sim_nr):
    sim = data[sim_nr]
    return(sim)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the square bracket selection and you even don't need a function:

```
df['Sim_1']
```